# Rsync problem...filenames

Tags: rsync, cygwin

I'm trying to back up users Chrome Sessions with Rsync with the following command:

```
rsync -e "ssh -i new.key" -r --verbose -tz --stats --progress --delete \
'/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Current Session' \
user@host:"/chrome sessions/"
```

Except this doesn't work exactly, as I get a file called chrome in a sessions directory that is already present on the server.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the space in "chrome sessions":

`rsync -e "ssh -i new.key" -r --verbose -tz --stats --progress --delete 
'/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Current Session' 
user@host:"/chrome\ sessions/"`

The double quotes are parsed and stripped by the local shell, keeping the two words together as a single argument to rsync. Rsync connects to the remote host and spawns a new shell.  That shell sees *two* arguments: "chrome" and "sessions".  If you have a quoted string with an embedded escape, the escape survives the trip to your remote host and tells the shell to ignore the space.

Answer (score -1):

try it like this:

rsync -r --verbose -tz --stats --progress --delete '/cygdrive/c/Users/jay/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/Default/Current Session' -e  "ssh -i new.key" user@host:"/chrome sessions/"